# PHP heredoc is not working when heredoc's string from MySQL text Type

Tags: php, mysql, heredoc

I store heredoc in MySQL text type like this.

```
Hi, $candidate.
This is $interviewer speaking.
```

I want to use heredoc dynamicaly like below.
("$mailTemplate->body" is string from MySQL text type above.)

```
$candidate = 'CANDIDATE';
$interviewer = 'INTERVIEWER';

$mailBody = <<< EOM
$mailTemplate->body
EOM;
```

But heredoc is not working, variables are output as they are.

```
Hi, $candidate. This is $interviewer speaking.
```

Any idea? Or is it impossible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cant do it like this. `$...` in your `$mailTemplate->body` is treated as text.

But you can use [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf) for this.

```
$text = "Hello %s this is a %s.";

$valueA = 'World';
$valueB = 'test';

echo sprintf(
    $text,
    $valueA,
    $valueB
);
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/RucvK).

#### output

```
Hello World this is a test.
```

Replace all the vars in your string by `%s` and provide the values as parametes in `sprintf`.

Comment: You saved my time. Thank you for your great answer and support!

Comment: You are welcome :) Feel free to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if its on point.